# How to set repository's social media preview via Github API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v4

I am working on a project where I want to set the social media preview for multiple (lots of repositories) I own. I know there is a manual way to do it as mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/customizing-your-repositorys-social-media-preview).
I was wondering if there was some way to do it via Github API or what kind of scripting could automate the task for adding social previews to multiple repositories.

Comment: Not sure about GitHub API, but for sure it is possible to do using Selenium. But, the question is whether time of Selenium script implementation will be shorter than manual update (unless you have 1k+ repositories) - I'm curious what do you consider as "lots of repositories".

Comment: Yes, time is not the only factor here so would be great if you could link to a selenium implementation of something similar here. To bring it to numbers, there are around 500 repositories and new repositories will be created and I am looking to add the social previews via script/API.

Answer (score 0):

If it was doable via the API, it'd almost certainly be one of the parameters at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-repository.  It's not there as of the time of this writing, but maybe someday.

There's sort of a feature request at https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/32166. It's unclear if there's a better place to make an API feature request.